# Network license control for a Java application

Tags: java

I have been tasked with providing some form of network license control for a Java application.  The app would be stored on a network drive and run from a client machine.  The basic idea is that it will be able to work out how many times it is being run concurrently and prevent the N+1th user from running the software where N is the number of concurrent licenses the customer has purchased.

Is this possible somehow with a Java application?  I implemented a "solution" which relied on multi-cast UDP communication between the running instances of the application but this didn't work because on most networks this kind of communication is blocked by security measures.

Is there a better way?  I don't even mind if it requires JNI/JNA.

N.B. The solution does not have to be that sophisticated or highly secure.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you go with an existing commercial license management product such as FlexLM.  It is doubtful that you will save any money by implementing a home-brew alternative.

---

> N.B. The solution does not have to be that sophisticated or highly secure.

If it is not secure, what is the point?

(You probably already know that it is impossible to build a license system that cannot be worked around or disabled in some way.  And that license management is a pain in the backside for your customers ... and indeed yourself, because of the extra customer support you have to provide.  And then there's the problem that you need to obfuscate your code, and that causes additional annoyance to your customers and support pain for you.)